# module not found despite successful Macports port install

Tags: python

EDITED -- very basic misunderstanding of proper path search order. Answered in comments below. Thanks!

---

What steps will reproduce the problem?
1. I installed healpy by :: sudo port install py27-healpy
2. this installation proceeded as normal
3. upon :: python (followed by) :: import healpy I received "ImportError: No module named healpy"

What is the expected output? What do you see instead?
I expected for healpy to load, as shown in the documentation tutorial

What version of the product are you using? On what operating system?
I'm using Python 2.7 on Mac OSX 10.9 (Mavericks) with a 64bit Intel Core Duo 2 MacBook Pro.

Please provide any additional information below.
The suggestion I've seen and heard has been to add /opt/local/bin and /opt/local/sbin to /etc/paths . I did this but still was unable to solve the problem

Comment: Make sure you are really using the MacPorts version of Python.  That's where any MacPorts-installed Python packages will be.  Try invoking Python with `/opt/local/bin/python2.7`.

Comment: This appears to work, but I'm confused. I have set python by :: sudo port select --set python python27 (as distinguished from python27-apple). What version of python is being run? How do I set the MacPorts one as the default?

Comment: The `port select` mechanism controls the symlink `/opt/local/bin/python`;  you need to make sure that `/opt/local/bin` appears on your shell `PATH` before any directories that contain `python`, for example, `/usr/bin` or possibly `/usr/local/bin`.  This is standard MacPorts foo; see https://guide.macports.org/#installing.shell