# how to compile fortran with minpack following successful macports install

Tags: fortran, static-libraries, macports, lapack, fortran95

Trying to write some fortran code calling some MINPACK routines (just new to fortran). [I installed minpack from macports](https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=minpack) without any trouble, but when I try to compile my code

`gfortran -o test testprogram.f95 -lminpack`

I get the error "ld: library not found for -lminpack". When I look in my usr/lib folder where my LAPACK library lives and which I've successfully used, I don't see MINPACK. Further, when I use the terminal command

```
locate minpack
```

all I get are files from my python libraries (scipy for example, wraps minpack for a lot of its functions). So I guess I have two questions: First, where is macports installing this package? That is an embarrassing question but if `locate minpack` can't tell me then I'm lost. Next, how can I set it up so that I could call it with the usual `-lminpack` term?

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26145724/module-not-found-despite-successful-macports-port-install) and my `/opt/local/bin` term is first in my $PATH variable (maybe that doesn't apply).

I'm running OSX-Yosemite. gfortran from GCC-5.1.

Comment: Do you know where macports installed the library?

Comment: No, is it possible that it sees the version of minpack that python is using and then doesn't actually install anything new? That would explain why only the python associated files show up with "locate".

Comment: I don't use macports myself but a bit of googling says it'll install in a location specific to macports, perhaps /opt/local/lib. If you do find it, you can tell gfortran to include that location in your library path with `-L/opt/local/lib`

Comment: You can use `port contents minipack` to get a list of the files installed by the minipack port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, macports installs everything under the prefix `/opt/local`, so any libraries will be located in `/opt/local/lib`.  To link against minpack provided my macports, you should include this path with a `-L` flag, which specifies a library search path.

```
gfortran -o test testprogram.f95 -L/opt/local/lib -lminpack
```